# Getting an array element index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, indexing

Is it possible to have an element of an array tell its position in JavaScript? If it is possible, it might come in handy when you have an array of objects and need to call on a method of one in the string of objects. You could pass its index as a method argument, but that seems messy and possibly unnecessary.

Ideally, it would be something like this:

```
function ArrayType(){

    this.showIdentity = function(){ 
        alert(this.indexOf()); // This obviously doesn't work, but I'm looking for
                                // a method that will return the index of "this" 
                                // in its parent array.
    }
}

var myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = new ArrayType;
myArray[1] = new ArrayType;
myArray[1].showIdentity(); // Should alert "1"
```

Would anyone know a sollution to this problem (other than passing the index along with the method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function ArrayType(parent){
    var p = parent;
    this.showIdentity = function(){ 
        alert(p.indexOf(this));
    }
}

var myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = new ArrayType(myArray);
myArray[1] = new ArrayType(myArray);
myArray[1].showIdentity(); // 1
```

This gives the elements a reference to the parent, that allows them to find themselves in their parent.

Answer (score 0):

The `indexOf` method is actually part of `Array.prototype`, so you should be calling it from your array object, and not from the actual object:

```
function ArrayType(){

    this.showIdentity = function(){ 
       console.log( myArray.indexOf(this) );
    };

};

var myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = new ArrayType();
myArray[1] = new ArrayType();

myArray[0].showIdentity();
```

This should work.

In case you want to have different arrays, there are two solutions I can think of. First would be to simply pass the array you want as reference and let the object ask it's index within that array:

```
function ArrayType(){

    this.showIdentity = function(array){ 

       console.log( array.indexOf(this) );

    };
};

var myArray       = new Array();
var mySecondArray = new Array();

var a  = new ArrayType();
var a2 = new ArrayType();

myArray.push(a, a2);
mySecondArray.push(a2, a);

a.showIdentity(myArray);  // 0
a.showIdentity(mySecondArray); // 1
```

Second would be to add a method to the Array prototype instead of having it be a method of the objects within:

```
Array.prototype.findIndex = function(object) {
  console.log( this.indexOf(object) );
};

function ArrayType(){};

var myArray       = new Array();
var mySecondArray = new Array();

var a  = new ArrayType();
var a2 = new ArrayType();

myArray.push(a, a2);
mySecondArray.push(a2, a);

myArray.findIndex(a); // 0
myArray.findIndex(a2); // 1
```

Of course, the prototype route is only valid in case you want to do more stuff other than getting the index. In case you just want the index, `indexOf` should be enough.